# Image viewer app: function to display next picture not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been watching this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) and had (I thought) a way better idea of solving the build an image viewer app.

But nothing happens on input, and I don't understand why, I think I might have totally misunderstood list as it doesn't start with the first picture (index 0).

The code is here

---

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
i = 0
root = Tk()
root.title("Learning to code")
root.iconbitmap('blue.PNG')

my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pics\me1.JFIF"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pics\me2.JPG"))
my_img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pics\me3.JPG"))
my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pics\me4.JPG"))
my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pics\pop.JPG"))
img_list = [my_img1,my_img2,my_img3,my_img4,my_img5]

my_label = Label(image=img_list[i])
my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

def f_fwd():
    global i
    global my_label
    if i < 4 :
        my_label.grid_forget()
        i =+1
        my_label = Label(image=img_list[i])
        my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

def f_bwd():
    return
    
button_bwd = Button(root, text= "<<")
button_bwd.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_quit =Button(root, text="Exit", command= root.quit)
button_quit.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_fwd = Button(root, text=">>", command=f_fwd())
button_fwd.grid(row=1,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Sorry if I worded the problem poorly.
I expected the index to go up and display the next picture in the list when the `f_fwd` function is called from the button command, and I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: `i =+1` should probably be `i += 1`

Comment: `command=f_fwd` without `()`

Comment: Solved. 
Thanks alot guys <3

Comment: Why are you removing the label from the grid and then putting it back? All you have to do in that loop is use `my_label.configure(image=img_list[i])` to set a new image on the `Label`. Also `my_label` is a terrible name. It doesn't give you any clue what it is used for. `img_slide` or something like that would make more sense.